# Respect Validation php slim custom messages

Tags: php, validation, slim, slim-3, respect-validation

I've read the docs and I wonder if its possible to make custom messages based on rules AND attribute, for example I have the following code

```
 $casoValidator =  Validator::attribute('nombre',Validator::allOf(Validator::stringType(),Validator::notOptional(),
     Validator::stringType()->length(3,100))) //nombre, validamos que sea cadena, que es obligatorio y que tiene de 3 a 100 caracteres 
    ->attribute('idUsuario',Validator::allOf(Validator::intType())) 
    ->attribute('numeroSertel',Validator::allOf(Validator::stringType(), Validator::stringType()->length(1,100)))
    ->attribute('dni',Validator::allOf(Validator::stringType(), Validator::stringType()->length(8,20)));                                                                  //la capturaremos al hacer insert si hay problemas con las FK


        try {
            $asuntoValidator->assert($asunto);

        } catch(NestedValidationException $exception) {
            $errors = $exception->findMessages([
                'length' => '{{name}} no puede tener mas de 100 caracteres ni menos de uno',
                'notOptional' => '{{name}} no es opcional',
      ....
```

as you can see, I have different length for 'nombre' and 'dni' so I should return two different messages, one that says
you can't have less than 3 character nor more than 100
and for dni I should return that dni can't have less than 8 charactes nor more than 20

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a separate `setTemplate` method call for each rule that is required for the custom template. For ex.:

```
    $rule = v::key('color', v::alnum()->setTemplate('{{name}} must be alphanumeric value, for ex. f7f1d5'))
        ->key('color', v::length(6,6)->setTemplate('{{name}} must be a 6-character value'));


    $params['color'] = '¯\_(ツ)_/¯';

    try{
        $rule->assert($params);
    } catch (NestedValidationException $e) {
        $errors = $e->getMessages();
    }

    var_dump($errors);
```

Result:

```
array (size=2)
0 => string 'color must be alphanumeric value, for ex. f7f1d5' (length=48)
1 => string 'color must be a 6-character value' (length=33)
```

Comment: Easy and elegant answer, a lot better that the one I did, I'll use this on my next project